# Jython setup in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jython

I have tried using PyDev Extension for VS Code. I intend to use vs code for Jython.
However, I get this

```
from java.util import Date
```

Date shows unresolved error in Vs code.
Can any one guide me how can Jython be setup in Vs Code?

Comment: What do you use Jython for? Have you managed to setup VSCode?

Comment: I use it for IBM Maximo. Jython is not supported in vscode

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to directly set Jython as the language in VS Code, but I got the file to run in Jython by entering jython in the VS Code terminal followed by the name of the file.

Comment: Running in terminal can be done even without vscode. I was looking to enable jython language features (code completion, syntax highlighting etc.) in vscode.